# Visual Studio - Make debug build strict

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

The project runs well in debug build, but when I tried to run in release build, the project just plunged into a sea of endless `access violation`.
For example, the first violation occurs at:
`log4cpp::PropertyConfigurator::configure(config_op->m_log4cpp);`
 `PropertyConfigurator` takes a `QString` parameter.
second at:
`middle_widget[0]->show();` `middle_widget[0]` is a `QWidget` object and already initialized.

Both `configure` and `show` are not possible to single-step into in release build and I can't get a clue of the reason to the violation.

Both violations seems accessing the same place `0xbaadf00d`:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77ad15de in Npptrail-Empty.exe:   
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf00d
```

It is said debug build is more tolerant than release build, which may leads to the release build run failure. But I don't want to make too much effort to clear all the access violations after debug build is complete. I want debug build the same strict as release.

Is it possible and how  ?

Comment: I wish my crystal balls weren't in the shop that way I could see some relevant code.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Sorry... I'm just looking for a way to strict the debug build. And the project has too many files and code, I can't post them all here.

Comment: log4cpp may contain different code between debug and release builds. Check the `#ifdef`s.

Comment: @CongXu the `#ifdef`s ? What are the `#ifdef`s ? I don't know much about `log4cpp`.

Comment: It's more "lenient" because it often does things like pad the stack frame. In the end, you're invoking UB, so either could fail (or not fail) suddenly.  For example, the debug heap is far better at catching invalid writes than the release heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

- Build release with debug info with turned off optimizations. In fact, it will be debug build but without debug MACRO. Sometimes it helps.
- [App Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It will raise an exception with explanation when you do something wrong with handles or critical sections.
- If nothing helps – try to debug release mode. Just run it under debugger. Depending on optimizations you may see the exception’s call stack and try to use some logging more precisely for further debugging.